# How can I split up a String in Dart and add dashes in between? (Flutter, Dart, Strings, Formatting)

Tags: string, flutter, dart, formatting

I have these types of UIDs here:

```
c4VTSVn3JfUxx9durORzj33UHfA2
```

and now I would like to receive this in my Dart code in Flutter:

```
c4VTSVn3-JfUx-x9du-rORz-j33UHfA2
```

I am looking for a way to split up strings in the UID-format and put it together again with the dashes in between.
How can I do that?

Comment: check `String.splitMapJoin` method

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me check this :)

Comment: I think as the string is completely random the splitMapJoin method makes it difficult to look for a specific section to cut (with a regEx). I think I would have to do it by the character count

Comment: `String uid = 'c4VTSVn3JfUxx9durORzj33UHfA2';
var i = 0;
final dashes = {2, 3, 4, 5};
final replaced = uid.splitMapJoin(RegExp('....'), onNonMatch: (s) => dashes.contains(i++)? '-' : '');
print(replaced);`

Comment: Wow, this is great, thank you so much!!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: @pskink better to give the solution as **Answer** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink this is a working solution:

```
String uid = 'c4VTSVn3JfUxx9durORzj33UHfA2'; 
var i = 0; 
final dashes = {2, 3, 4, 5}; 

final replaced = uid.splitMapJoin(RegExp('....'), onNonMatch: (s) => dashes.contains(i++)? '-' : '');

print(replaced);
```